# How does negative performance of a portfolio constituent affect its weight?

Tags: portfolio-management, finance, finance-mathematics, portfolio

This is an easy question, I hope.

Suppose we have a swap A with a long position, which, originally, has a weight of 30%. Over time, it has a positive performance of 3%, meaning we have a multiplier of 1.03 relative to its original value.
Hence the resulting weight would be 30% * 1.03 = 30.9% (as a % over original portfolio value).
This makes sense, because you expect the value of the holding in A to increase as its performance increases, hence so will the weight.

If we now have a swap B with a short position with an original weight of -20%, and the swap performance is -2% (0.98 relative to original value), we would expect the portfolio to perform better as you benefit from the drop in value of the swap.

How would I work out the resulting weight as  % of  the portfolio's original value? Is it simply a case of -20/0.98 = -20.4%? A mathematical explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: 30% * 1.03 = 30.9%, not 39%

Comment: @amdopt Thanks - edited (accidental slip!)

Comment: Isn't the new weight -20*0.98 = -19.6? You have profited from the bad performance (positive P&L) but you now have a smaller short position as the result of that performance. (But I am not an expert on swaps).

Comment: I've been told that it's not -19.6% unfortunately...?

Comment: Do you need to calculate the value after both A and B change?

Comment: @BobJansen  I've been told A is correct (30.9%). I just need to know how to do it for B as a % of original portfolio value.

Comment: @BobJansen do you have any insights on this?

Comment: Not really I’m afraid. Do you know the correct answer? I think someone should be able to reverse it.

Comment: @BobJansen I've been told -20/0.98 = -20.4% is a 'good approximation' of the new weights as a % of original value and I want to show why that works. I also thought the correct way of calculating might just be -20 * 1.02 and this is close enough to -20/0.98 hence why the former is called a good approximation, but unsure

Comment: What kind of 'swaps' are these, FX swaps?

Comment: @noob2 they're just TRSes but I don't think that should matter too much